# Transfrerring Ether onto exchanges bought in aud

Tags: exchanges

Hello and thanks in advance for your assistance.

I am in the process of transferring my ether bought in AUD from Coinspot and there third party affiliate wallets into myetherwallet or the like (as nano ledger s is sold out) to manage my own affairs and I was wondering how I then go about using those ethers on Poloniex or Kraken or any other exchange that would support the transfer of my ether coins purchased with fiat aud for the purpose of converting those coins back into aud? (As Coinspot now charge 6% on transfers (which is still a heck of a lot better than their original 10% spread. High fees and terrible service seems the norm over there)

Any recommendations you could may would be much appreciated as my knowledge of trading on exchanges for alt coins and fiat currency is limited, not through lack of effort but an extremely complicated space with a lot of misinformation.

Thanks

Mark

Comment: Hi there. Your question has been flagged, I'm afraid, as it's asking for recommendations, which usually lead to opinion-based answers, which aren't a good fit for this site. I think the EthTrader Reddit board would be a better place to ask: reddit.com/r/ethtrader

Answer (score 0):

Simply register on any of the exchanges you want to trade on, get you ether address from your account and transfer your preferred from MEW to the exchange.